# Counter not working but by manually entering it work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I created a counter like so `var count=-1;` and everytime user presses a button it adds one to the counter like so `onclick="count++"` then i added these two lines:

```
var emal = $("[name^=date").eq(count).val(); 
$("[name^=date").eq(count-1+2).val(emal-1+2);
```

But when I put "count" after `.eq(` it doesn't work, but when I put 0 and 1 instead of count, respectably, it works. Why is that? How can I fix it? And how can I make this input more into a label than a input?

This is what I'm trying to make...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV2CQ.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzvFF.png

Comment: include the code snippet in the way that code could be copy/pasted.

Comment: see code http://pastebin.com/hGD6wqXM line 61 and 62

Comment: @user1869391, can you share the error

Comment: there is no error it just doesnt work...http://iqamah.org/timetable/test.php

Comment: see the attached two pics...

Comment: @celerno code uploaded

Comment: @RohitAgrawal see pictures plz

Comment: It's clear that I don't understand your question. It would be better if you made a small fiddle with a few lines of code that adds say one or two elements, and then it would be easier to help. The code you point to is VERY long.

Comment: I think I've figured out your issue - in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/9amrtpue/ - and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @TimSPQR Thank you for your help i still cant figure it out...i created a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/004zg8tw/
also see image
http://i.imgur.com/GrZyhn1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I think I understand your question - and my first impression was right - you have to treat your append text like a string.

Here is your updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/004zg8tw/1/).

Note that the "blocks" of your string between the counts are surrounded by double quotes, and all of the "quotes" in between the double quotes are single quotes.

I didn't try to get the styling down exactly, but you can play around with inline, block, inline-block, span, div, input, etc.

I didn't necessarily get your "count" correctly because I don't understand how you increment (on your hand drawing you do 1, 6, 11...????

Just remember that javascript/jQuery loves strings, and you can use that to your advantage in many different ways.

```
  $("#container").append(
                         "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-1 col-md-offset-1'> <h4><strong><span class='putmehere'>" + count + "</span> </div> <div class='col-md-1 '><input  type='number' class='form-control' value=' " + ((+count-1) + 5) +  " ' name ='date[]' id = field[1]- required /><p></p> </div>  </div> "
                        );
```

Comment: I still dont understand how should I add that with a span??

Comment: thank you i will try to play around with it. The increment is (user input +1) so if user inputs 5 then the the count will be 6...